# "pacman -Syu" 'probably' broke my system, because boot was not mounted

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, pacman, arch-arm

I am running 4.9.61-1-ARCH armv7l on my RaspberryPi2.
I broke my system by upgrading it. To fix it, I used chroot into sdc2 from another Arch ARM installation, but I didn't mount the boot partition sdc1 out of incompetence.
I ran `pacman -Syu` and now my system boots again, and runs fine as long as I can tell, however I got the following warnings:

```
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM] upgraded linux-raspberrypi (4.9.61-1 -> 4.9.65-1)
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] WARNING: /boot appears to be a seperate partition but is not mounted.
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]          You probably just broke your system. Congratulations.
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] >>> Updating module dependencies. Please wait ...


[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM] running '99-linux-raspberrypi.hook'...
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux-raspberrypi.preset: 'default'
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> -k 4.9.65-1-ARCH -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-linux.img
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Starting build: 4.9.65-1-ARCH
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [base]
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [udev]
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [autodetect]
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [modconf]
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [block]
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [fsck]
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> WARNING: No modules were added to the image. This is probably not what you want.
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: /boot/initramfs-linux.img
[2017-11-28 22:34] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Image generation successful
```

Another `pacman -Syu` told me 'there is nothing to do'

Now I'm wondering whether this can cause problems, perhaps with future upgrades. Is it recommended to downgrade linux-raspberrypi and run the upgrade again or am I in safe waters here, since it seems to work?

The modification dates of the contents of the folder /boot match the modification dates of the boot partition, so I copied them like suggested in the comments -- works fine.

Comment: copy all files from /boot to your real boot partition then mount it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, copy everything in /boot to a temporary directory,

```
$ sudo cp -R /boot /tmp/boot
$ ls /tmp/boot # verify that everything copied over
```

Then delete everything in /boot,

```
$ sudo rm -ir /boot/*
```

Then mount your boot directory,

```
$ sudo mount -a # mounts all filesystems mentioned in fstab
$ sudo mount | grep boot # verify boot is mounted
```

And then copy everything back into /boot,

```
$ sudo cp -R /tmp/boot/* /boot/
$ ls /boot # verify files copied over successfully
$ sudo rm -rf /tmp/boot # delete temporary directory
```